# KineticJS mouse over canvas remove

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, mouseover

I'm trying to make on online webgame.
I want to be able to spawn a cube inside a canvas and when you hoover over it I want it to be removed.

I'm a newcorner at Javascript but this is my code so far

```
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'gamebox', //Find an HTML element
        width: 553,
        height: 498
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer(); // Don't know what this shit is doing

    var numEvents = 0;

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({ // Create a cube
        x: 239,
        y: 75,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
    });

    rect.on('mouseover mousedown mouseup', function() {
        numEvents=++numEvents;
        document.getElementById("energycollector").innerHTML=numEvents;
        context.clearRect ( 239 , 75 , 50 , 50 );
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(rect);
    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

`context.clearRect` is used in html5 canvas to overwrite part of the canvas, but it does not apply when using KineticJS.

In KineticJS, your rect is an object so you would remove that rect like this:

```
// to remove the rect, but not destroy it (you could later re-add it to the layer)

rect.remove();

// OR, to remove and destroy the rect

rect.destroy()
```

Good luck with your game!